# C# open and edit excel file inside windows forms

Tags: c#, excel

**What I've done:**
I am trying to be able to open an excel file in a windows form so that I can create a disposable pivot table. I have tried a few options that I've found on Google but I've run into a brick wall. 
One option that I found was to open in wpf user control document viewer, while I can open the file I cannot edit it.

I have not figured out a way to edit the excel file.
**My Question**: I need to display a blank excel sheet inside a windows form, then I will need to add a pivot table to the sheet that is embedded inside the windows form where when the form closes it disregards the sheet that was open in the form. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why not just open it in excel and make the changes?  Are you looking for the entire feature set of excel within a windows form?

Comment: no, I just need to be able to create a disposable pivot table on it

Comment: What is a "disposable" pivot table?

Comment: just a pivot table that doesn't have to be created in the current excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all tasks related to programmatic construction or manipulation of Office documents, the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is the proper solution. All other APIs are either limited in scope (other 3rd-party Excel writer APIs support only a subset of the features of Excel documents) or have issues being used programmatically (Office automation is notoriously error-prone and should NEVER be used in a server environment). The Open XML SDK allows you to directly create and manipulate the data structure that is the Office document. It does not require Office to be installed. Additionally, the Open XML Productivity tool (also available via the download link below) will allow you to open an existing document and see EXACTLY the code required to construct EXACTLY that document. Very useful!

Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: You should note though that the Open XML SDK is great for working with Excel documents, it does not provide any sort of UI functionality to display or allow the user to interact with the data.

Comment: thank you, will this allow me to give to someone that doesn't have VS on their machine?

Comment: Yes. Once you compile your program, you would simply give the .exe and the dependencies (which will include the Open XML SDK assembly) to your user. That user will be able to use your program without VS or Office installed. However, they must (of course) have Office installed to open the document once you have programmatically constructed it.

Comment: i'm sorry to keep asking, I've downloaded and added this to the references, but I cannot figure out how to add to form? can you provide another link?

Comment: It doesn't go on a form. There is no UI associated with the Open XML SDK. It's just for programmatically manipulating documents. If all you want to do is manipulate a document, this is a perfect solution. If you want to DISPLAY a document, you'll have to find something else.

Comment: Download the productivity tool and open a document with it to see how this SDK is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82720/discussion-between-user3120232-and-michael-gunter).

Comment: It used to be that there were a few competing third-party APIs for server-side Office document generation, but one of the products was acquired by Microsoft and I haven't kept up with the other, so OOXML is the way to go.